# Range(A) and Columns

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix. Show that
(a) $Null(A)=\{0\}$ if and only if the columns are linearly independent. (b)$Range(A)=\mathbb{R}^{m}$ if and only if the columns span $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
I have finished the (a), but I have tried (b), but can not get any idea. Does the (b) has something wrong with itself?

Comment: It should read "if and only if the columns span $\mathbb{R}^m$."

Comment: The Rank Plus Nullity Theorem said that $dim R(A)+dim N(A)=n$ for all $m\times n$ matrices. But the "$Range(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$".

Comment: The columns of $A$ are $m \times 1$ vectors, so it doesn't make sense to say they span $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I also think so, but this problem occurred in a qualifying exam. Can you give me a counter-example?

Comment: I can't give you a counterexample.  The question is just formulated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If we write $A = (v_1 | \cdots | v_n)$ so that the k-th column of $A$ is $v_k$, then $Ae_k = v_k$ for all $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, where $e_k = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ is the $k$-th vector in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. By definition, a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is an element of $Null(A)$ if and only if $Ax = 0$. Since $x = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e_k$ for some real numbers $a_k$, we can write
$$Ax = A(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k e_k) = \sum_{k=1}a_k Ae_k = \sum_{k=1} a_k v_k.$$
So the equation $Ax = 0$ is the same as $\sum_{k=1} a_k v_k = 0$, which is an equation of linear dependence of the columns of $A$ unless $x = 0$.

As Ink noted earlier, statement (b) should say that $Range(A) = \mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if the column vectors of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$, which we now prove. By definition $Range(A) = \mathbb{R}^m$, if and only if every $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is of the form $y = Ax$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \iff x = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e_k$, we can conclude $Range(A) = \mathbb{R}^m \iff$ every $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is of the form $y = A(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k e_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k v_k$. Thus $Range(A) = \mathbb{R}^m \iff \text{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} = \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: In "By definition.......for some $y=Tx$", what is the "$T$"?, I think it should be $A$.

Comment: You are correct. I seem to have switched from $T$'s to $A$'s in my second paragraph for some reason. It's corrected now.